# How to include JSON file/object inside C++ at build time

Tags: c++, c, json, cmake

I have a JSON File with database environment configuration called env-config.json like this:

```
{
"LATEST":{
"DB_DATABASE":"databasename",
"DB_HOST":"hosturl",
"DB_PORT":"3306",
"DB_USER":"root",
"POOL_MAX":1
},
"PROD":{
"DB_DATABASE":"databasename",
"DB_HOST":"hosturl",
"DB_PORT":"3306",
"DB_USER":"root",
"POOL_MAX":1
}
}
```

is in the root of source of a c++ project

so i want to easy touch that config in a json format but use it from my compiled c++ code for example

when the program is running query to the system what environment is, like

```
system.getEnvironment()
```

system says "PROD"

in that moment call to that JSON file and extract the info to use in the program.

the problem is that i need a method to distribute the json together with the final executable i can not have the binary and json file in separately files.

i try with:

```
file (STRINGS "env-config.json" CONFIG)

add_definitions (-DENV_CONFIG=${CONFIG})
```

and after that use that string in the program, but the problem is that the cmake crash because all the scapes from the json, yes i can put the json in string format with a lot of \n and scapes, but i will lose the json format readably.

So is possible for example have my json file intact in json format and in build time cmake convert it to string and after that use

```
file (STRINGS "env-config.json" CONFIG)

add_definitions (-DENV_CONFIG=${CONFIG})
```

or if that is so complicated because the JSON format

is possible use a properties file like java

db-${env}.properties

with this content

```
db.database.name = mydatabasename
db.database.url = myurl
db.database.user = root
db.database.password = root
```

and include it together inside the executable like in a MAP inside config class or struct

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure it's possible. You write a declaration of a map or a string, just like a declaration of any other map or a string, that contains whatever your data you want to be included. Since this is, pretty much, normal C++, it's really unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Add the text to a cpp file, then switch depending on the configuration. Don't put the configuration as a macro, that's bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm either misunderstanding your use case or you're missing an important point about including the file at build time.

The point of having a JSON configuration file, if I understand correctly, is for system administrators to be able to configure the application at any time. However, injecting the JSON file into the application at build time means it will baked into the executable binary forever. *The only way for the changes in the JSON file to take place is to rebuild the application again.*

If that is what you want, I would suggest to simplify your life and make the configuration a header file that you can simply include in your source code (instead of JSON) similar to this:

**config.h**

```c
#define LATEST_DB_DATABASE "databasename"
#define LATEST_DB_HOST     "hosturl"
#define LATEST_DB_PORT     3306
#define LATEST_DB_USER     "root"
#define LATEST_POOL_MAX    1

#define PROD_DB_DATABASE   "databasename",
#define PROD_DB_HOST       "hosturl"
#define PROD_DB_PORT       3306
#define PROD_DB_USER       "root"
#define PROD_POOL_MAX      1
```

If that is not possible then you need to write a build script in any language that reads the JSON file and converts it into a header file similar to the one shown and that header gets included in the source code and compiled with it.

However, if you don't want to include the JSON file at build time then you will need a JSON library written in C to read the configuration file at runtime.